# How to create an object (class) made by objects (classes) in ruby?

Tags: ruby, object

Imagine I have an object "House". Inside the "House" I have want to have an object "Door" and an object "Window" with its different methods, lets say open and close doors/windows. 
My main goal is to have code that looks like this:

```
my_house = House.new
neighbor_house = House.new

my_house.Door.open
neighbor_house.Window.close
neighbor_house.Door.open
neighbor_house.Door.close
my_house.Door.close
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to create the class House, in order to have the class Window and Door inside of it.

Comment: mareiou, please edit your question to include your comment that answers mudsie's question, and delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Though I do not understand, why you decided to ask this question here instead of reading some introduction to Ruby language, the answer follows:

```
class Door
  def open; end
  def close; end
end
class Window
  def open; end
  def close; end
end
class House
  attr_reader :door, :window
  def initialize door, window
    @door, @window = door, window
  end
end

house = House.new Door.new, Window.new
house.door.open
house.window.close
```

Comment: Upvoting and adding my 2 cents. @mareiou I would suggest also looking into object oriented programming principles. In this specific case you would want to create methods in `House` class like `#open_door` or `#close_window` instead of calling them on returned objects. This is guided by [Law of Demeter](https://www.google.com/search?q=Law+of+Demeter). Alternatively, create another class that takes instances of your classes and do operations on them, like `HomeManager`. This is guided by [SRP principle](https://www.google.com/search?q=SRP).